# Does DS.FixtureAdapter has sideload support?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using DS.FixtureAdapter and can't get related entries using DS.belongsTo

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    login: DS.attr('string'),
    profile: DS.belongsTo('App.Profile')
});

App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
    fullname: DS.attr('string'),
    address: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('user', { path: ':user_id' });
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.User.find(params.user_id)
  }
});
```

Is it only a feature of Rest Adapter?

**update**

The fixture data is something like this:

something like this:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      login: "marlus",
      profile: 1
    }
];

App.Profile.FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      fullname: "Marlus Araujo",
      address: "Rio",
      user: 1
    }
];
```

Comment: It's available in the FixtureAdapter, what does your fixture data look like?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Note that the fixtures adapter doesn't "eager-load" fixtures, so you have to account for the run-loop when you access the association.

Comment: I've tested (Ember RC6) it declaring the Store like this:

    `App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
    });`

And it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Ember Data (1.0.0-beta4), has a new syntax for configuring a model with a fixture adapter.

```
App.UserAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1, firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Roberts'
}];

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return this.get('store').find('App.User', params.user_id);
```

Also, this could be helpful: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-a-record/